# The ACTIVE command can only be used on fixed MBR disks

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, mbr

I installed Ubuntu as a Dual boot, the webcam did not work so I tested several solutions that I found on the web, when they failed and I made a restart to the OS, I got a message `/dev/sdb7: recovering journal ...`, so I wanted to delete all the partitions I allocated for the Ubuntu and reinstall. After deleting all the partitions except the partition where the operating system (C) is installed and the partition labeled EFI, I restarted the computer and it showed me that Windows Boot Manager is missing. (I had some healthy partitions that I only could delete them using Powershell, when I right click on them in the `Disk Managemnent` it only showed `help`, those partitions I have not allocated by myself, I took the risk and delete them.)

I followed this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/accidentally-deleted-windows-10-boot-partition-how/181745f9-3303-4968-9851-5c213db9c89c

Now when I run `list disk` in DISKPART then it shows me two disks:

`Disk 0`, which is the SSD on which the operating system is installed.

`Disk 1`, which is - USB Flash Drive that contains the installation media.

Running `select disk 0` lets me select it.

In the `list partition` step, I am presented with:

```
Partition 1 System 100MB

Partition 2 Primary 446GB

Partition 3 System 515MB
```

Partition 3 is the add-on of create partition efi

Running `bcdboot c:\windows` gives:

`Failure when attempting to copy boot files`

I tried to launch Ubuntu from USB flash drive, in the Ubuntu installation type, I choose `Something else`  it shows me that the EFI partition that I had not deleted is `Windows Boot Manager` so I don't understand what happened.

How do I restore Windows Boot Manager to boot the existing SSD and get back an access to Windows OS?

Thanks.